# SceneKit Update Methods "Update" or "DidEvaluateActions"

Tags: scenekit

i'm used to use to use SpriteKit for my games. Recently i've started to use SceneKit but i could not found the same method like "Update", or "DidEvaluateActions" for SceneKit.

How can i implement those methods in SceneKit?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the `SKSceneDelegete` is the [`SCNSceneRendererDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate) .